# Match version number parts in grok

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I want to split a version string (e.g. 2.3.5) into three fields(major.minor.patch) using the grok filter.

What I tried:

`%{NUMBER:major}.%{NUMBER:minor}.%{NUMBER:patch}`

Result from [Grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com):
`No Matches`

[image]
What I expected:

```
{
    major: 2,
    minor: 3,
    patch: 5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of the version number are *int* values, hence, it makes sense to use `INT` rather than `NUMBER` that matches more than just integer values.

Besides, the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Use

```
%{INT:major}\.%{INT:minor}\.%{INT:patch}
```

Test:

[image]

**More details:**

The patterns are available in [logstash repository](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.0/patterns/grok-patterns):

```
INT (?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))
BASE10NUM (?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))
NUMBER (?:%{BASE10NUM})
```

So, the pattern that results from `${NUMBER}...`  is

```
(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+))).(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+))).(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))
```

and it [does not match the input string](https://regex101.com/r/FqgtCO/2) because the `(?>...)` atomic group matches the dot as part of a float number and never gives it back since backtracking is disallowed into atomic group patterns.